# Check valid datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have form search

```
<b><span>@Html.Raw(Generic.ToDate):&nbsp</span></b><span>@Html.DateEmpty("ToDate", (DateTime?)ViewBag.ToDate)</span>
<b><span>@Html.Raw(Generic.FromDate):&nbsp</span></b><span>@Html.DateEmpty("FromDate", (DateTime?)ViewBag.FromDate)</span>
```

I have code js input datepicker:

```
  $("input[type=date]").each(function () { this.type = "input" }).datepicker();
```

I want check validate fromdate < todate and date > "30/9/2013". please who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Read [date range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

**js**

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
```

Comment: i want save sesion date went i iput, example: went  i input 10/9/2013 after klick search input save 10/9/2013, but now went i input 10/9/2013 after kick iput disble value 10/9/2013, text box is emty. Please help me